Assembly program not clearing the GPIO pin on my Raspberry Pi 4
How's it going, I figured that I would come back to this problem after a couple of months, I made a gpio driver in ARM64 assembly for the Raspberry Pi 4, but the clr0 offset isn't working for me to flash the led, here is the code.
.global _start

.equ RDWR, 00000002
.equ SYNC, 00010000
.equ RESOLVE_IN_ROOT, 0x08
.equ MAP_SHARED, 0x01
.equ PROT_READ, 0x1
.equ PROT_WRITE, 0x2
.equ PAGELEN, 4096
.equ offset17, 21
.equ GPFSEL1, 0x04
.equ GPSET0, 0x1c
.equ GPCLR0, 0x28

_start:
    ldr x0, =RESOLVE_IN_ROOT /* Means you want to access another directory starting from root */
    ldr x1, =devmem      /* The pathname for devmem as a zero placed string */
    mov x2, #(RDWR+SYNC)     /* Read, and Write flags plus Sync to enable i/o operations of the returned file descriptor */
    mov x8, #0x38
    svc 0
    adds x4, xzr, x0     /* The returned file descriptor */
    bpl Mmap
    mov x0, #1
    ldr x1, =errmessage
    ldr x2, =len
    mov x8, #0x40
    svc 0
    b exit
Mmap:
    ldr x0, =gpioBaseAddress /* The base address for the gpio pins */
    mov x1, #PAGELEN     /* Page length, which is 4096 */
    mov x2, #(PROT_READ + PROT_WRITE) /* Pages may be Read, and Written */
    mov x3, #MAP_SHARED       /* Updates to the mapping are visible to the other processes mapping the same region */
    /* adds x4, xzr, x0 from the openat function, so the returned file descriptor from opening dev/gpiomem */
    orr x5, x5, xzr           /* We dont need this parameter, so just put 0 */
    mov x8, #0xde
    svc 0
    adds x9, xzr, x0          /* The returned file descriptor of the virtual page of memory created at the mapped address of 0xfe200000 */
    bpl Select
    mov x0, #1
    ldr x1, =errmessage
    mov x2, #len
    mov x8, #0x40
    svc 0
Select:
    mov x1, #0b001
    lsl x1, x1, #offset17
    str w1, [x9, #GPFSEL1]       /* Each instruction interacting with the gpio pins has to be 32 bit, or else you will recieve a bus error, store the 3 bit value in x1 in the gpfsel1 offset address to set pin17 as an output */

loop:
    add x10, x10, #1
    mov x1, #1
    str w1, [x9, #GPSET0]
    ldr x0, =timeamount
    ldr x1, =timeremaining
    mov x8, #0x65
    svc 0
    str w1, [x9, #GPCLR0]
    mov x0, =timeamount
    mov x1, =timeremaining
    mov x8, 0x65
    svc 0
    cmp x10, #10
    bne loop
    b exit

exit:
    mov x0, #0
    mov x8, #0x5d
    svc 0
.data
devmem:
    .asciz "/dev/gpiomem"
errmessage:
    .asciz "couldn't obtain file descriptor"
len = .-errmessage
gpioBaseAddress:
    .word 0xfe200000
timeamount:
        .word 1
timeremaining:
        .word 0

I tried changing the offset around on GPCLR0 even though the datasheet said that that was the offset, but it didn't work.

I understand this is most likely for the educational purposes, but one should never use that gpiomem interface. It is a brain fart with no portability, race free, and who knows what else. If you really want as fast GPIO as possible, consider not to use Linux, rather one of the available RTOSes, e.g., zephyr.

Here's one bug:
    ldr x0, =gpioBaseAddress
gpioBaseAddress:
    .word 0xfe200000

The pseudo-instruction ldr x0, =foo loads x0 with the value of foo.  But here gpioBaseAddress is a label, so its value is the address of the label.
If you actually wanted the value 0xfe200000 in x0, you'd have to do another load:
    ldr x0, =gpioBaseAddress
    ldr w0, [x0] // w0 because gpioBaseAddress is .word which is 32 bits

But better would be to just define it as a constant, rather than as a data object in memory:
    .equ gpioBaseAddress 0xfe200000
    ldr x0, =gpioBaseAddress

You have another problem with your calls to nanosleep.  Each argument should be a pointer to a struct timespec which consists of two 64-bit elements, but you have them pointing only at a single 32-bit element.
If you have more bugs (which is very possible), you should investigate them by single-stepping with a debugger such as gdb, inspecting register and memory contents as you go, as well as using strace to see what system calls are actually being made by your program.
